# Prolog Change for Dollar

Tags: prolog

Define a rule to find the changes (numbers of half dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies) of a given amount S, where 0 < S < 100 (pennies). The format of the rule should be

```
change(S, H, Q, D, N, P)
```

I have:

```
change(S, H, Q, D, N, P) :-
member(H,[0,1,2]),                      /* Half-dollars */
member(Q,[0,1,2,3,4]),                  /* quarters     */
member(D,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) ,    /* dimes        */
member(N,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,       /* nickels      */
           11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]),
S is 50*H + 25*Q +10*D + 5*N,
S =< 100,
P is 100-S.
```

Each time I run it for example :

```
| ?- change(87, 0, 3, D, 1, P).
```

or this

```
| ?- change(73, H, 2, 1, N, 3).
```

I just get no as the result

Answer (score 1):

You are missing pennies in the formula. Then, when you query an odd amount (actually, any amount not multiple of nickels, that is the smaller unit you coded), it cannot be satisfied. So, add pennies in the computation, and remove the useless last 2 lines.

As a style note, Prolog offers between/3, so your code could be cleaned up like

```
change(S, H, Q, D, N, P) :-
 between(0,2,H), /* Half-dollars */
 etc etc...
```